# Auto tuning of PI,PD,PID controller for a given transfer function

Tags: python, matlab

I am working on auto-tuning of the classical controller(P,I and D). Specifications of the problem.

1. Plant transfer function 10/(s+1)
2. Phase Margin of whole system(plant and controller) must changed to 60 degree.

I am following the book "Introduction to Control" by Karl J. Astrom. In the book, there is a method to find the approximate range of the gain cross over frequency(w_gc). The method is given below

```
       argP(i*w_gc)+argC(i*w_gc)>=-pi+phase margin
```

PI controller has phase lag between 0 and pi/2. So the gain crossover frequency range is

```
      -pi+phase margin<=argP(i*w_gc)<=-pi/2+phase margin
```

After applying the same approach on the given plant the range of the frequencies become

```
       0.577<=w_gc<=1.732
```

If one can know about the gain crossover frequency then he can design the controller at that frequency. Here is my question. How to choose a proper gain crossover frequency in this range? The **pidtune** function of **Matlab** gives 1.1237 rad/s as the gain crossover frequency. How one can find this frequency?

Comment: Do you need this automated or can you perform some operations by hand?

Comment: I want to write a code about auto-tuning. So I need it automated.

Comment: There are multiple algorithms based on different heuristics for this. There is no universal answer, as an easy TF plant can be made to behave as you wish, but more complex model are based in iterative methods and so on. MATLAB gives av alue, which is not the best, just a feasible answer. This is an open research topic, so unless you have an specific question about a specific method, it is too broad.

Comment: Thanks @Ander Biguri for giving me right approach to think about the solution. Now I am designing a PI controller. The design specifications- Plant*Controller have phase crossover 60 degree and it (plant and controller) have highest sensitivity margin in given frequency range that I mentioned in my problem statement.